# KeyError: 'value' error in logging into the ASP.NET website using python requests?

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.4

I am trying to login to a .aspx website using python requests.This works with other websites properly but messing up with .aspx websites.Anyways
**What I have tried :**
(Simple but looks Complicate due to names please go through the code)

```
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
"X-MicrosoftAjax": "Delta=true",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

with requests.Session() as s:
url = 'https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/Default.aspx'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)

login_data = {'ScriptManager1': 'SchSel$up|SchSel$btnLogin',
              '__LASTFOCUS': '',
              '__EVENTTARGET': '',
              '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
              '__VIEWSTATE': soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"],
              '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"],
              'SchSel$cmbUserType': 'Student',
              'SchSel$txtUserName': 'user',
              'SchSel$txtPassword': '1234',
              'SchSel$chkSkip': 'on',
              'SchSel$hidLastLogin': "Last Login: NIIT University | 2016-2017",
              'SchSel$hidSchoolId': soup.select_one("#SchSel_hidSchoolId")["value"],
              'SchSel$hidSchoolName': soup.select_one("#SchSel_hidSchoolName")["value"],
              'SchSel$hidCoreUserDet': soup.select_one("#SchSel_hidCoreUserDet")["value"],
              'SchSel$hidSessionId': '8',
              'SchSel$hidActiveSchool': '1',
              'SchSel$hidHitCount': soup.select_one("#lblTotalHit").text.split(":", 1)[1].strip(),
              'SchSel$hidReportingDet': '0',
              'SchSel$hidActiveSession': '1',
              'SchSel$hidSchoolAddress': 'Address',
              'SchSel$hdnLoginAsUser': '',
              '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
              'SchSel$btnLogin.x': '42',
              'SchSel$btnLogin.y': '14'
              }
s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

res = s.get('Protected page')
```

---

This throws an error

> KeyError: 'value' error for (soup.select_one("#SchSel_hidCoreUserDet")["value"])

So,When I got through the source code of the webpage I want to login.**This is the part of page Source** of the page I want  to login.

```
if (obj != null) {
        obj.onreadystatechange = ProcessResult;
        obj.open("GET", "GetLoginData.aspx?username=" + userName + "&categoryid=" + categoryId + "&URL=" + document.URL + "&TIME=" + new Date(), true);
        obj.send(null);
    }
    return false;
}<br>
```

**Process result Function:**

```
 function ProcessResult() {
    var stock;
    if (obj.readyState == 4) {
        if (obj.status == 200) {
            var cmbUserType = document.getElementById("SchSel_cmbUserType");
            var categoryId = cmbUserType.selectedIndex;
            var chkAutoLogin = document.getElementById("SchSel_chkAutoLogin");

            if (obj.responseText != "") {
                var dataarr = obj.responseText.split(':');
                var lblSchoolHit = document.getElementById("lblSchoolHit");
                var lblCount = document.getElementById("lblCount");
                var lblLastLogin = document.getElementById("SchSel_lblLastLogin");
                var hidCoreUserDet = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidCoreUserDet");
                var hidSchoolId = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidSchoolId");
                var hidSessionId = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidSessionId");
                var hidActiveSchool = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidActiveSchool");
                var hidReportingDet = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidReportingDet");
                var hidActiveSession = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidActiveSession");
                var hidHitCount = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidHitCount");
                var hidSchoolAddress = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidSchoolAddress");

                if (dataarr[0] == "" || dataarr[0] == null) {
                    chkAutoLogin.checked = true;
                    chkAutoLogin.disabled = false;
                    lblLastLogin.innerHTML = " Last Login: " + hidSchoolName.value + " | " + arrlist[4];
                    hidCoreUserDet.value = arrlist[0];
                    hidSchoolId.value = arrlist[2];
                    hidSessionId.value = arrlist[3];
                    document.getElementById("SchSel_hidLastLogin").value = "";
                    lblLastLogin.innerHTML = " Last Login: " + hidSchoolName.value + " | " + arrlist[4];
                    hidActiveSchool.value = arrlist[5];
                    hidReportingDet.value = arrlist[6];
                    hidActiveSession.value = arrlist[7];
                    lblSchoolHit.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    lblCount.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                else {
                    var arrlist = dataarr[0].split('|');
                    hidCoreUserDet.value = arrlist[0];
                    if (hidCoreUserDet.value != "") {
                        var hidSchoolName = document.getElementById("SchSel_hidSchoolName");
                        hidSchoolName.value = arrlist[1];
                        hidSchoolId.value = arrlist[2];
                        hidSessionId.value = arrlist[3];
                        hidActiveSchool.value = arrlist[5];
                        hidReportingDet.value = arrlist[6];
                        hidActiveSession.value = arrlist[7];
                        hidHitCount.value = arrlist[8];
                        hidSchoolAddress.value = arrlist[9];
                        lblLastLogin.innerHTML = "Last Login: " + hidSchoolName.value + " | " + arrlist[4];
                        document.getElementById("SchSel_hidLastLogin").value = lblLastLogin.innerHTML;
```

I am sure that there is something wrong with giving the value for **SchSel$hidCoreUserDet** because only if `obj.response not =""` values are assigned.

So,any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that SchSel_hidCoreUserDet element even exists in the document?  The javascript code in ProcessResult() may just be setting it to undefined, whereas your python code throws an exception if it's missing.

Comment: If the SchSel_hidCoreUserDet element does exist, what is it exactly?  What attributes does it have?

Comment: Yes,it exists.See in processResult function if `obj.responseText != ""` and else for `if (dataarr[0] == "" || dataarr[0] == null)` only the `hidCoreUserDet.value = arrlist[0];` value is assigned.

Comment: It has no value so that is the error, `<input type="hidden" name="SchSel$hidSchoolName" id="SchSel_hidSchoolName" />`

Comment: see `if` loop here `hidCoreUserDet.value = arrlist[0];` it assigns value only `if (dataarr[0] == "" || dataarr[0] == null) `.how to satisfy the if loop then in order to assign value?

Comment: See the screen shot ![Screenshot](https://s9.postimg.org/qlrf36rkf/Screenshot_100.png)

Comment: When did you take the screenshot?

Comment: This is [second screenshot](https://s9.postimg.org/78y33f6jz/Screenshot_101.png) august 14 12:40 IST